# Create RedirectResult from T4MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm trying to set `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult`, using T4MVC

My existing call is:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/account/login?ErrorCode=" + ServiceLocator.ExceptionHelper().NotLoggedInError.Code);
```

which I want to replace.

**Is this possible with T4MVC?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the *best* way, but this works:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action(MVC.Account.Login(ServiceLocator.ExceptionHelper().NotLoggedInError.Code)));
```

Comment: For anyone who is interested, if you want to access Url from outside the view, you can still access it by getting HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.Url